# Can I get ST3 to kill the previous instance of my program before starting another when building?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

In my project settings, I have a build system that looks like this:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "name": "My Python Builder",
        "selector": "source.python",
        "shell_cmd": "/.../env/bin/python -u \"/.../main.py\""
    }
],
```

This way I can run my program from anywhere in the project with `cmd-B`. The problem is, unless I explicitly exit the program, when I run `cmd-B` again it just launches another instance. Is there a way to get Sublime to kill the previous instance launched via Build when I build again?

Comment: have you considered storing the pid of the python process to a file when you start it in the `shell_cmd`, so that you can reliably know the pid of the previous instance? see [how to get the pid of the just started process as a one liner](http://serverfault.com/a/205504)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've bodged this to work by making my program write out its own pid, then doing the following:

```
"shell_cmd": "kill -9 `cat /tmp/myapp.pid`; env/bin/python -u main.py",
```

Comment: Usually ctrl+break calls _exec:kill_ (cancel build kills the current build proccess). If this works for you then you can use a plugin to run multiple commands with a single keybinding and run _exec:kill+build_